# How to replace file extension name in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

how to replace a file name and extension in react.js public folder.

---

### convert to index.html to index.php

---

### [image]

**

Comment: https://medium.com/@davisonpro/an-advanced-guide-on-setting-up-a-react-and-php-web-app-acaedb21ab3a
check this post, check the entryPoints section

Comment: You're asking how to rename a file?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot you should be able to click on the file name, then hit the enter key to rename the file. If you arrow to the right you can also edit the file extension.

Comment: when the change to index.html to index.php my app not working. I try PHP XAMPP  server but not working

Comment: @solooo7 when I change the public folder index.html file extension  to index.php and  start PHP XAMPP server my app not work